# How to put values from database to object properly in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Table in database which has structure like this;

```
ID | Process_Id | Attribute   | Parent_Id | Sequence
----------------------------------------------------
1     1          INDIVIDUAL     
2     1          FIRST_NAME         1         1 //parent_id is same as ID of its parent
3     1          SECOND_NAME        1         2
4     1          INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS   1   
5     1          ALIAS_NAME         4         1
6     2          sdnEntry       
7     2          firstName          6         1
8     2          lastName           6         2
9     2          aka                6   
10    2          firstName          9         1
11    2          lastName           9         2
12    1          ENTITY     
13    1          FIRST_NAME        12         1
14    1          ENTITY_ALIAS      12   
15    1          ALIAS_NAME        14         1
```

My classes for setting values to this data is look like this;

**Update my previous code to `DataAdapter`**
    public class Attribute 
    {
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public List ParentNodes { get; set; }
    }

```
public class ParentAttribute
{        
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string parentNodeValue { get; set; }
    public List<ChildAttribute> ChildNodeValues { get; set; }
}

public class ChildAttribute
{
    public int sequence { get; set; }
    public string childNodeValue { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    //public List<GrandChildAttribute> childNodeValue { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChildAttribute
{
    public int sequence { get; set; }
    public string grandChildNodeValue { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
}
```

this how I am trying to place values in objects, Updated code

```
public static Attribute GetProcessAttributes()
    {
        using (OracleConnection oCon = new OracleConnection(Con))
        {
            Attribute att = new Attribute();

            string query = @"SELECT * from Process where Process_Id = :Process_Id";                
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, oCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Process_Id", 1);
            oCon.Open();
             OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(rdr);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    att.ProcessId = Convert.ToInt32(row["Process_Id"]);

                    att.ParentNodes = new List<ParentAttribute>();
                    var pNodes = (from pRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  where pRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == null
                                  select pRow).ToList();

                    foreach (var pItem in pNodes)
                    {
                        ParentAttribute pAtt = new ParentAttribute();
                        pAtt.parentNodeValue = pItem["Attribute"].ToString();
                        pAtt.id = Convert.ToInt32(pItem["ID"]);

                        pAtt.ChildNodeValues = new List<ChildAttribute>();

                        var cNodes = (from cRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      where cRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == pAtt.id
                                      select cRow).ToList();


                        foreach (var cItem in cNodes)
                        {
                           //how to handle when childnode has further childs
                            ChildAttribute cAtt = new ChildAttribute();
                            if(cItem["Sequence"] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                cItem["Sequence"] = 0; //was unable to pass null value to Integer type in ternanry so did this
                            }
                            if (cItem["Parent_Id"] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                cItem["Parent_Id"] = 0;
                            }
                            cAtt.childNodeValue = cItem["Attribute"].ToString();
                            cAtt.sequence = Convert.ToInt32(cItem["Sequence"]);
                            cAtt.parentId = Convert.ToInt32(cItem["Parent_Id"]);

                            pAtt.ChildNodeValues.Add(cAtt);
                        }
                        att.ParentNodes.Add(pAtt);
                    }                               
                }                   
            }
            return att;
        }

    }
```

Now I am able to place values inside my object, I would appreciate, But the issue is that some of child nodes have single value and some contains further list, how do I assign type  to that property on run time. 
In my current case , two parent nodes **"INDIVIDUAL"** and **"ENTITY"** each parent has its own child as identified by `parent_Id` parent_Id to parentNodes is considered null are empty, further child has some granchildnodes tooo.

Comment: You want to get all parents of  specific Process by entered `Process_Id`?

Comment: parents and their respective childs too

Comment: So you need to iterate it recursively, do you know how you can do it recursively ?

Comment: @Aria I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think for getting all parents of a process based process id you should do something like:

Suppose each of row that you mentioned in your table is a process so to get all parent process do something like:

```
string end = string.Empty; 
List<Attribute> attributes= new List<Attribute>();
int searchId = childId;
do
{
    var processes =//Select from your table where Id = proccess_Id
    foreach (Process ps in processes )
    {
        end = ps.ParentID.ToString();
        attributes.Add(ps);
        proccess_Id= ps.ParentID;
    }
} while (end != string.Empty);
```

note: `string.Empty` is end of the hierarchy relation !.

To Get All child of Process you can do something like :

```
 void GetChild(IEnumerable<Process> data, int? parentId = null)
{
    var items = data.Where(d => d.Parent_Id == parentId).OrderBy(i => i.MenuOrder);
    if (items.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //Each Item is your child 
            GetChild(data, item.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

but you can `join` the table with itself to find parent of each row something like :

```
SELECT child.Id, child.Name, parent.Id, parent.Name
    FROM Process AS child
    LEFT JOIN Process AS parent ON child.ParentId = parent.Id;
```

Comment: will this map to my object class

Comment: Actually no, you should improve it as you want, this is just a solution  and would give you the clue

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need multiple classes as all of them represent one table. I would rather have a single self referencing class which will set up the tree for me. The class might look something like this:

```
    public class Process
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get; set;

        }

        public int ProcessId
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int Sequence
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<Process> Children
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
```

This will hold all the records regardless of their location in the tree. Now to parse the records, I am assuming you are getting the data in reader same way as it shown in the table. Also, there is no need to change it to table.

I have tried to put up a really quick and dirty code to traverse the tree to find the node. As long as the depth is not a lot and number of records are fairly low, you can iterate through the list to get the right parent.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
        OracleDataReader reader = null;

        int? parentId = null;
        Process currentProcess = null;

        // Assumes that query results are ordered in a way that parent records appear before the child records
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Get the parent id from reader. Change index as per your need
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1) && ((parentId = reader.GetInt32(1)) != null))
            {
                currentProcess = GetProcessRecord(processes, parentId);

                // add values to children to current process here
            }
        }

    }

    private static Process GetProcessRecord(List<Process> processes, int? parentId)
    {
        Process currentProcess = null;
        // This record has a parent. See if we already have it.
        if (processes.Any(x => x.Id == parentId))
        {
            // Found the parent record at level 0
            currentProcess = processes.First(x => x.Id == parentId);
            if (currentProcess.Children == null)
            {
                currentProcess.Children = new List<Process>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Might be a child record of another parent
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                if (process.Children != null)
                {
                    currentProcess = GetProcessRecord(process.Children, parentId);
                    if (currentProcess != null)
                    {
                        return currentProcess;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return currentProcess;
    }
```

As I mentioned earlier, this is quick and dirty so you might need to optimize the code and probably the approach to traverse as well. You might also want to make use of parallel execution if that is fitting for your needs.

To test whether the recursion works, following code can be used:

```
        /* 
         * Set up the tree
         *       1
         *       |-4
         *       | |--10
         *       | |--11
         *       |-5
         *       2
         *       |-6
         *       |-7
         *       3
         *       |-8
         *       |-9
         */
        processes.Add(new Process { Id = 1, Children = new List<Process> { new Process { Id = 4, Children = new List<Process> { new Process { Id = 10 }, new Process { Id = 11 } } }, new Process { Id = 5 } } });
        processes.Add(new Process { Id = 2, Children = new List<Process> { new Process { Id = 6 }, new Process { Id = 7 } } });
        processes.Add(new Process { Id = 3, Children = new List<Process> { new Process { Id = 8 }, new Process { Id = 9 } } });
        var test = GetProcessRecord(processes, 11); // Test for various values
```